# XPath query with variable multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Long-time listener, first-time caller. I'm relatively new to XPath and looked at several other threads here and elsewhere but I can't seem to get a query working, any help would be great.

I have XML as follows:

```
<catalog>
  <book pgid="28054" lang="en">
    <title>The Brothers Karamazov</title>
    <author>Dostoyevsky, Fyodor</author>
    <friendly_title>The Brothers Karamazov by Fyodor Dostoyevsky</friendly_title>
    <file>
      <type>ePub</type>
      <path>cache/generated/28054/</path>
      <name>pg28054.epub</name>
      <size>800</size>
    </file>
    <file>
      <type>PDF</type>
      <path>2/8/0/5/28054/</path>
      <name>28054-pdf.pdf</name>
      <size>5829</size>
    </file>
    <file>
      <type compression="zipped">PDF</type>
      <path>2/8/0/5/28054/</path>
      <name>28054-pdf.zip</name>
      <size>1693</size>
    </file>
    <file>
      <type encoding="utf-8" compression="zipped">Text</type>
      <path>2/8/0/5/28054/</path>
      <name>28054-0.zip</name>
      <size>726</size>
    </file>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

(catalog is the root element, and in this example there are no `<contributor>` elements)

I have the query working on author, contributor, title, and language searches, but I am getting hung up on adding a file type condition. This query to find books with author OR contributor containing "Dostoyevsky" and title containing "Brothers" with language "en" is *working* (i.e. giving expected results), but if there's a better way to write it I'm all ears:

```
/catalog//book/*[(contains(self::author,'Dostoyevsky') or contains(self::contributor,'Dostoyevsky')) and contains(../title,'Brothers') and ../@lang = 'en']
```

What I *can't* get to work is limiting the query results to files of a certain type, i.e. appending `and ../file/type='PDF'` or something. Didn't have any luck with `|` unions either.

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and if it matters, the query needs to be built dynamically (from form input), so it needs to retain a universal syntax that would work with any number of user-supplied criteria.

Comment: Please, do your homework and at least provide real, well-formed and meaningful XML document.

Comment: What is it you want, Dimitre? This _is_ my real XML. I didn't think the content was relevant.

Comment: @swornabsent : Dimitre is right, your XML is not well formed. The way you write your lang attribute is not XML. You should update your question to make it valid (e.g. lang="...").

Comment: Ok, sorry to confuse. There's more going on here than is relevant to this particular question, and I was just trying to supply the relevant template and so opted for some shorthand. Naturally the content is of lang='en' (or whatever).

Comment: @swornabsent: Even if you fix the issue with the attribute, would you bother to fill the elements with content? What you have provided looks more like a "skeleton" of a real XML document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get you right, this should work :

```
/catalog[file/type='PDF']//book/*[(contains(self::author,'Dostoyevsky') or contains(self::contributor,'Dostoyevsky')) and contains(../title,'Brothers') and ../@lang = 'en']
```

Note that the filter is directly on the `catalog` element.

If you try to get `book` elements, maybe you should use `/catalog[file/type=...]//book[test1][test2][test3]...` with your different constraints. Each new test act as a filter.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that clears things up. I got ahead of myself.

Comment: the same logic works also when you want to test something on  next siblings i.e.  `... and contains(text(), 'Some text 1') and ../td[4] = 'Some text ...`

Answer (score 1):

> This query to find books with author OR contributor containing
>   "Dostoyevsky" and title containing "Brothers" with language "en" is
>   working (i.e. giving expected results), but if there's a better way to
>   write it I'm all ears:
>
> ```
> /catalog//book/*[(contains(self::author,'Dostoyevsky') or contains(self::contributor,'Dostoyevsky')) and
> ```
>
> contains(../title,'Brothers') and ../@lang = 'en']

The XPath expression above is not only quite imperfect and absolutely un-formatted and unreadable, but, more importantly, it doesn't (as stated) select any `book` element at all (it may select an `author`). Also, the `//` pseudo-operator isn't necessary and may significantly reduce the efficiency of XPath evaluation on any real world moderate to large XML document.

**Here is an XPath expression that selects what you want**:

```
 /catalog/book
    [@lang='en'
    and
     file/type='PDF'
    and
     *[self::author
      or
       self::contributor
       ]
        [contains(., 'Dostoyevsky')]
       and
         contains(title, 'Brothers')
     ]
```

> Oh, and if it matters, the query needs to be built dynamically (from
>   form input), so it needs to retain a universal syntax that would work
>   with any number of user-supplied criteria.

This "universal syntax may look something like this:

```
/*/book
   [
    contains(*[name() = $pName1], $pString1) 
   and
    contains(*[name() = $pName2], $pString2) 
 . . . . . .
   and
    contains(*[name() = $pNameK], $pStringK) 
    ]
```

where `$pName1`, `$pName2`, ..., `$pNameK` should be substituted by the names of the fields the end user has specified in the search form, and

`$pString1`, `$pString2`, ..., `$pStringK` should be substituted by the data that the user has indicated should be contained in the corresponding fields.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. This has been a bit skunkworks, and I initially had some server-side PHP logic locating the desired parent element depending on what kind of results were produced. This is helpful, as have been your other responses.

Comment: @swornabsent: You are welcome. I just updated my answer to give you an idea about the requested "universal syntax" -- enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way for doing this is to filter for the two/three conditions separately and join them,

```
<xsl:for-each select="//catalog//title[contains(., 'Dostoyevsky')] | //catalog//author[contains(., 'Brothers')]">

</xsl:for-each>
```

The pipe (|) will combine each result